# jquery multiple id selector

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have the following code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert and Show Records using jQuery Ajax and PHP</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    //insert record
    $('#tagid').click(function(){
        //var idis = $('#tagid').val();
        var idis = document.getElementById("tagid").name;
        alert(idis);

        //syntax - $.post('filename', {data}, function(response){});
        $.post('test2.php',{action: "insert", tagidis:idis},function(res){
            $('#result').html(res);
        });        
    });

});
</script>
</head>
 <body>

<?php
$key = 1;
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"".$key."\" id=\"tagid\"";
echo " style=\"width: 20px; height: 20px;\">";
$key = $key+1;
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"".$key."\" id=\"tagid\" style=\"width: 20px; height: 20px;\">";
?>

<p>Result:</p>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I execute it, where $key =1, it does the alert and shows 1.
But when I select the second checkbox, it does not show the alert.

How in jquery do I have it listening for ALL the checkboxes with the id "tagid" instead of just the first?

Comment: All `id`s _must_ be unique within a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add a class to the inputs and use a class selector like $(".myClass")

Comment: and in this case you can get what you want this way in the click function:

    $('.myClass').click(function(){ var idis = $(this).attr('name'); ...

Answer (score 1):

`id` attribute is unique.

From the [JQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM.

This is why it only works for you for the first one.

You should use class selectors instead.